# angular 4 nested reactive form add input on value change to parent of input ONLY

Tags: javascript, angular, nested, textfield, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with nested formarray group. I have an input that is added on when user type/select **other: ** (there is a space after the colon ( : ))  . But the input is showing everywhere not just next to the selected/parent input it shows up next to all the inputS that have the same name.
Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snxpfs?file=src/app/app.component.html) .
How can I have the other input field show just next to parent input?
[image]

[code with CSS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etseoz)

Comment: it would be much more easier to help you if you included css in the plunker as well. Also please clarify what exactly you wish to achieve, from what I understood it has something to do with the css itself.

Comment: when a person name is other: , an input field pops up for that person. When the person name is different from other: , we don't have an input popping up for that/those person/people. Or if it pops up it should be disabled for the person with a name different from other: .

Comment: Here is the code with the CSS :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etseoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question you are trying to change some flags per row, but you write values of those flags to a global variable.
What you can do is to pass `personRow` as parameter to the function which handles the change and then depending on the event type set the flag in the `personRow` object itself. That way you can achieve higher level of granularity in control over the behaviour of your form.

Modified stackblitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnaebz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

P.S. please consider separating your component into a set of smaller/reusable ones, it will be easier to manage and easier to modify.